# Why does iOS insist on using my Facebook email address?

Tags: ios, contacts, facebook, mobile-safari, auto-complete

I fill out webforms on my iphone fairly often. I use autocomplete to speed this process along, and it works pretty well for the most part. However, for some reason, it always insists on using an @facebook.com email address in the email field.

I do not use Facebook for email. I never have, never will, and never want to. I *do* use Facebook for lots of other things, and thus, would prefer not to turn off iOS's Facebook integration, which seems to be the only workaround that googling has offered me.

**How can I force auto-complete to use my preferred email address, rather than the one associated with my Facebook account?**

Answer (score 4):

Go to account settings in Facebook (web) -> general -> email

Untick "use your Facebook email"

You may need to then re sync your Facebook contacts.

Hey presto... It's sorted!!

Comment: The location seems to be now: Account settings > email address

Comment: I found I needed to restart the phone after unlocking the Facebook account and and then re-logging in

Answer (score 3):

Open up your contact card that is linked to your autofill

Change the label on your facebook email to 'other' or something else and change the label on the email that needs to be auto filled to 'email' or 'home' if 'email' is not available.

If that doesn't work unlink facebook and link facebook again. Facebook should now be at the bottom.

Autofill should pick the top email address.

Comment: It won't let me change the label of the Facebook email, sadly. But I can just change the label of an email that's listed above it to simply 'email' if that'll fix it. I had an email labelled 'home' which it was bypassing to use the facebook account.

Comment: According to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/message/19858017) that should fix it. But if not try unlinking your facebook and linking that again. And if that doesn't work you could clear your autofill in settings->safari->autofill

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, you need to go to System Preferences > Mail, Contacts & Calendars, select your Facebook account then untick the Contacts checkbox http://take.ms/AD4o8V

Then you can select any of the fields in your Contacts app and "reclaim" your desired main email address.

Comment: Except that I *want* Facebook linked to my contacts. I would rather have that than autofill working properly.

Comment: Understand, I took the compromise route, I unlinked from FB but kept all the contacts I got from it.

Answer (score 1):

First, I created a new contact in my contacts for myself with just my email, and the other specific info I want used for autofill in it, using a name that was not at all similar to the one currently being used (i.e. "hello kitty" or something that you will be able to easily pick out).

Then, I went into Settings → Safari → Passwords & Autofill → My Info. Then type the name you previously created into the search box to choose it as the info you want used for autofill.

Voila! This worked for me.

Comment: Well, you'll want the contact to have your real name, or else it'll fill "Hello Kitty" in web forms! But this solution definitely does work.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer for this that worked for me.
1. Go into your contact information and 'unlink' your facebook contact from your regular contact.
2. Go into settings > mail, contacts, cals and make sure the correct contact is selected (non-facebook contact)
3. Go into settings > safari > pws & autofill and again make sure the correct contact info is selected
4. Go back into your contact information and re-link your facebook and your regular contact info.

My worked fine after this and got my gmail.  Man this was bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

I went into Settings and then scrolled down to Facebook (it was in the 7th group of items listed together in a white box background) and in there under "Allow these app to use this account" I turned the little slidey-switch-thing to off.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your iOS Facebook app. On the left side tap on General then tap email then scroll to the bottom , you will see **use your Facebook email**. Uncheck the box.
2. Go back to your iPhone contact list, scroll and find your name, click edit on the top left side. Scroll down until you find the notorious Facebook email. This time it will have a red button where you can delete it. After deleting the next email on line will be your default email.If you dont have another email on the list just type your preferred email and its done.

Answer (score -1):

Remove the facebook email address from your facebook account. then resync contacts.